# Is there a way to save values between iterations of a Python algorithm?

Tags: python, csv

I have a class which prints some data to a CSV file. The data is calculated by an algorithm elsewhere in my code, and a list of results is sent to the below method.
There is one element in the results which we want to see how it's changed from the previous results, and save the values for future comparison. I saved these values in a dictionary where I use the name (another one of the values I'm given) as the key, but now I encountered a test case where two types have the same name, and there are no other immutable values I can use. This is not a problem anywhere else in the code (the algorithm doesn't care about their names) but I'm at a loss as to how to differentiate them.
The results should be in the same order every time, but I don't want to count on this.

The best solution I could come up with was to add a $ sign to the end of the name (see hotfix below), but this looks sloppy to me and still relies on the values being in the same order. Alternatively, I could create a list or array instead of a dictionary, which would be neater but more order-dependent.

```
from csv import writer

class CSVPrinter():
    def __init__(self, filename=None):
        self.filename = filename if filename else "test_file"
        self.prev_totals = {}

    def write(self, rows):
        """ Write given rows to CSV file """
        with open(self.filename, "a", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
            writer(csv_file).writerows(rows)

    def print_results(self, results):
        """ Print results (already calculated) """
        new_totals = {}
        sum_change = 0
        for res in results:
            title = res[0]
            while title in new_totals:
                title += "$"  # hotfix
            change = res[4] - self.prev_totals.get(title, 0)
            res.append(round(change, 4))
            new_totals[title] = res[4]
            sum_change += change
        self.write(
            results + [["", "", "", "", "", round(sum_change, 4)]]
        )
        self.prev_totals = new_totals

csvp = CSVPrinter("test_file")
# Print sample data. Normally print_results() would be called from within the algorithm.
csvp.print_results([["Res_A", 100, 200, 100, 100], ["Res_A", 200, 200, 300, 200], ["Res_B", 400, 200, 300, 200]])
csvp.print_results([["Res_A", 100, 300, 0, 200], ["Res_A", 200, 300, 100, 200], ["Res_B", 200, 0, 50, 500]])
```

Expected results: (csv)

```
Res_A,100,200,100,100,100
Res_A,200,200,300,200,200
Res_B,400,200,300,200,200
,,,,,500
Res_A,100,300,0,200,100
Res_A,200,300,100,200,0
Res_B,200,0,50,500,300
,,,,,400
```

Is there a neater way to handle this problem without having to create more data (such as a unique ID created elsewhere in the system)?

Comment: You said you are looking for order independent solution, but If you forget the order what relates Res_A ( first element first list ) with Rest_A (first element second list) not with Res_A(second element of second list)?

Comment: @AnuragRegmi This is what I'm trying to figure out. They are separate objects outside of this code, in the algorithm. I'm looking for a way to differentiate them here.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary where you store your memorised values needs an id and a stored value. If you can't rely on (or don't want to generate) a unique ID, then the second option available to you is to store the values you associate to your non-unique key in a list or other collection data type. This allows you to store and retrieve the contents by the existing key without concern.

e.g. an example of this structure might be:

```
mem_store = { "name1" : [ 1, 4, 55 ], 
              "name2" : [ 6 ] , 
              "name3" : [ 4 ] ,
              "name4" : [ 3, 6, 99 ] }
```

Your function that works with these data values would of course have to change to accommodate reading them in as a list. This may be impractical, but you don't mention what exactly your comparison function does, so I'm assuming some comparison is possible in this way.

If it's something simple like a `sum`, `avg` or other numeric aggregation, then this ought to work out fine.